# css transition on mouseout appears delayed

Tags: css-transitions

I'm trying to add transitions to a list of items where mouse over causes the  item to expand by changing max-height.
The expand on mouse enter happens immediately but the mouse out transition is delayed.

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cawkie/u2eLh18f/2/

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .inner {
            border: solid 1px #000000;
            width: 300px;
            max-height: 30px;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 10s linear 0s;
        }

        .inner:hover {
            max-height: 10000px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            Lorem ipsum dolor ....
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            Lorem ipsum dolor ...
        </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Possibly not relevant, but the JS mouse-out event is immediate.

Am I missing something? 
Is there a workaround?
If this is normal/intended - why?

I could use JS/jQuery but was trying not to :-)

Comment: The reason it is delayed is because the `max-height` value is way bigger than the actual content. If you adjust its value to be slightly higher than the content it will look better.

Comment: Thank you - obvious when it's pointed out :)

Answer (score 0):

If your not opposed to using Bootstrap, they have a really nice [accordion implementation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example) you could use the achieve this effect without writing your own Javascript. If you do want to implement it yourself, you can add their CDN link to your page, then use Chrome DevTools to inspect the CSS in the Sources tab. Just prettify it and Ctrl+F search for the relevant classes.